# Custom response header not sent

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I have developed some OWIN middleware to appends a custom header to the response. However, in my integration tests (which uses OWIN `TestServer`), I cannot see the custom header in the response object.

I notice that I do see the location header which I populate for POST requests.

I also notice that the header is appearing when I make real requests to the service.

Does anyone know why I can't see the custom header in case of `TestServer`?  Is there settings I need to make to allow these?

Here is the OWIN middleware:

```
private async Task CalculateTimeToProcess(IOwinContext context)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    await Next.Invoke(context);
    sw.Stop();
    var response = context.Response;
    response.Headers.Add("x-timetoprocessmilliseconds",
        new[] { sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
}
```

This is how I am trying to retrieve the header in my test:

```
var header = _restContext.HttpResponseMessage.Headers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == "x-timetoprocessmilliseconds");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the difference is between your live setup and unit-test, but you should be aware that if any previous middleware starts writing to the `response.Body`, the headers are getting sent before the OWIN pipeline returns to your middleware (see Note below).

What you can do is attaching a callback to [`OnSendingHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.iowinresponse.onsendingheaders%28v=vs.113%29.aspx#M:Microsoft.Owin.IOwinResponse.OnSendingHeaders%28System.Action%7BSystem.Object%7D,System.Object%29) before you invoke the next middleware.

```
private async Task CalculateTimeToProcess(IOwinContext context)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
    {
        sw.Stop();
        var response = (IOwinResponse)state;
        response.Headers.Add("x-timetoprocessmilliseconds", new[] { sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) });
    }, context.Response);
    await Next.Invoke(context);
}
```

**Note**: By sending the headers first, they can transmit whatever gets written into the body stream directly to the socket without having to buffer that in memory. This also means that your measurement will be incorrect in case other middleware already writes to the output stream while still processing things...